# What is the best way to reshape tensor in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, reshape

I have a conv net that outputs a tensor w/ shape (28, 397, 256). I want to restructure it to create a tensor of (28*256, 397) while preserving the order of the 397 axis, which is a time dimension. Once reshaped I want to feed it to another layer in the model.

Keras's Reshape layer didn't preserve the order. I was thinking I could take the output tensor of the conv net and manually splice it into a new one, but I don't know how to "input" that tensor back into the next layer of the model. Help would be appreciated, I'm new to keras.

Heres what I tried initially:

```
conv = Conv2D(hidden_units, kernel_size, strides=(1,1), activation=conv_activation)
model.add(conv)
conv_output = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_kernel)
model.add(conv_output)

### STACKING ###
shape = conv_output.output.shape
F_prime = shape[1].value
T = shape[2].value
M = shape[3].value

reshaped = core.Reshape((T, F_prime*M), input_shape=shape[1:])
model.add(reshaped)

recurr = LSTM(hidden_units, return_sequences=True, activation=recurr_activation, recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid', dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.0)
model.add(recurr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `concatenate` found in in `tf.concat` or `np.concatenate`. In your case you want to merge axis `0` and axis `1` so you can do `tf.concat(tensor, axis=0)`.

You can also use `tf.reshape(tensor, (28*256, 397))`. Note the number of elements of before and after sizes must be the same!

Hope this helps!

Comment: I understand that I can do that, but how do I integrate the reshaped tensor into the model layers? I can achieve the reshape using:

split = tf.split(conv_output.output, M, axis=3)
reshaped = tf.squeeze(tf.concat(split, axis=1), axis=-1)

Where conv_output.output is the output tensor that needs to be reshaped. But how would you specify that as an input to the next layer? I guess I could rewrite everything in tensorflow to avoid this issue but ideally I'd like to use keras

Comment: You can call tf functions from Keras. `from keras import backend as K` and `K.concat(...)`

Comment: Solved - created a custom keras layer and used backend operations